# How to use onListen callback to start producing events?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a broadcast stream to start emitting events only after there's a listener, because if there are no any listeners at the time the events just being dropped.

If I use single-subscription stream it works ok, but only if I enter the screen for the first time. The second time it shows an error `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.`,  so I've decided to switch to broadcast.

I've tried it the way [suggested](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/17305) by one of the Dart's developers I've found on github.

```
StreamController.broadcast(onListen: () => _cacheLength.sink.add(0));
```

The error message is `Only static members can be accessed in initializers.`

Any suggestions on how to add events to the sink at onListen?

---

### CarsListScreen.dart

```
import './../../bloc/provider.dart';

int _itemCount = 200;

class CarsList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.provideBloc(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  stream: bloc.cacheLength,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                      if (snapshot.data != 0) {
                        _itemCount = snapshot.data;
                      }
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: _itemCount,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return StreamBuilder(
                              stream: bloc.cars,
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.hasData &&
                                    snapshot.data != null &&
                                    snapshot.data.length > index) {
                                  return Text('''
                                          ${snapshot.data[index].brand}
                                          ${snapshot.data[index].model}
                                          ${snapshot.data[index].year}''');
                                } else {
                                  bloc.addId(index);
                                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                }
                              });
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  })),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

### bloc.dart

```
import './../data-sources/carsCache.dart';
import './../models/carModel.dart';

class Bloc {
  Bloc() {
    init();
  }

  CarsCache cache = CarsCache();

  //stream cars from cache to cars-list screen//
  StreamController<List<CarModel>> _cars = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream<List<CarModel>> get cars => _cars.stream;

  //stream IDs to load from cars-list screen to cache//
  StreamController<int> _carIds = StreamController();
  Function(int) get addId => _carIds.sink.add;

  //stream cache length to cars-list//
  StreamController<int> _cacheLength =
      StreamController.broadcast(onListen: () => _cacheLength.sink.add(0));
  Stream<int> get cacheLength => _cacheLength.stream;

  void init() {
    _carIds.stream.listen((id) {
      if (cache.repo.length <= id) {
        cache.fetchCarsFromDB().then((endOfList) {
          if (endOfList) {
            _cacheLength.sink.add(cache.repo.length);
          } else {
            _cacheLength.sink.add(0);
          }
        });
      }
      _cars.sink.add(cache.repo);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking the declaration apart from the assignment:

```
  StreamController<int> _fin;
  _fin = StreamController<int>.broadcast(onListen: () => _fin.sink.add(0));
```

If that's not it, post more of you code so we can see the context.

Change your updated code like this....

```
  //stream cache length to cars-list//
  StreamController<int> _cacheLength;

  Stream<int> get cacheLength => _cacheLength.stream;

  void init() {
    _cacheLength =
        StreamController.broadcast(onListen: () => _cacheLength.sink.add(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work, the error is  `The name '_fin' is already defined.`
The question is updated to provide more information.

Comment: That means that `_fin` is already declared somewhere. Post the code where this occurs.

Comment: You must have a syntax error in your code. Prune it down to as small a sample as you can that shows the error and post the whole of that sample.

Comment: You will get that error if you insert that code outside of a method. Leave the declaration outside, then move the assignment into the constructor or any form of `init` method.

Comment: Not sure why I can't put new lines in the comments, sorry for clumsiness.

No, it's not declared anywhere else. I even did a text search for the whole profect to be sure.
I've renamed `_fin` to `_cacheLength` in my code above to be more clear.

This works:
`StreamController<int> _cacheLength = StreamController<int>.broadcast();` 
This does not: 
`StreamController<int> _cacheLength;
  _cacheLength = StreamController<int>.broadcast();`


Errors: _The name '_cacheLength' is already defined._ and _Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name._

Comment: It works. You were right - the code was outside of any method. Thanks a lot!