# StreamBuilder not refreshing after asyncMap future resolves

Tags: flutter

I'm using the following StreamBuilder in a Stateful widget:

```dart
StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
  stream: widget.model.results(widget.type),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error');

    final List<int> results = snapshot.data;
    return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: results.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return _buildListTile(results[index]);
                  });
  })
```

And here's the bit where the Streams get built:

```dart
// inside the ViewModel
late final List<StreamController> _streamControllers = [
  StreamController<List<int>>.broadcast(),
  StreamController<List<int>>.broadcast(),
];
List<int> _results = [];

Stream<List<int>> results(int index) =>
  _streamControllers[index]
      .stream
      .debounce(Duration(milliseconds: 500))
      .asyncMap((filter) async {
    final List<int> assets = await search(filter); //  Future
    return _results..addAll(assets);
  });
```

The issue is that the UI doesn't get rebuilt after the `search` results are returned.

The debugger shows that the Future is getting resolved correctly, but that the UI doesn't get rebuilt once the result is returned (within `asyncMap`).

Am I using `asyncMap` correctly? Is there an alternative way to set this up that could potentially get it working?

**EDIT:** Showing the code that adds events to the stream

```dart
[0, 1].forEach((index) => 
    textController.addListener(() =>
        _streamControllers[index]
            .sink
            .add(textController[index].text));
```

Comment: Could u please show code where u add events to stream? U are using asyncMap correctly. But you might not be adding event(s) to stream correctly.

Comment: @Nuts added. That's unlikely to be the case, because the initial query triggers asyncMap — but the process is not resumed after completion of the Future.

Comment: Then by any chance u are rebuilding widgets, like with setState? Otherwise, builder is not listening when this event is done....

Comment: Yes, the view model extends `ChangeNotifier` and the root widget for this screen is a `Consumer<ScreenViewmodel>` that gets rebuilt whenever the model changes. Are you saying that model changes may be triggering a rebuild that clears previous listeners to the stream?

Comment: Might be, try to change controllers into `BehaviorSubject` - if it works - that is you problem

Comment: can you explain `_results..addResults(assets);`? I don't understand what's it's trying to do. List does not have addResults method. Is it an extension?

Comment: @user6327816 you can consider it the equivalent of an `addAll` -- I don't actually use a `List` but a custom class. I'm using a List in the example to simplify the reproducible example for the problem.

Comment: Hi @FloatingRock, I would love to help you but I am afraid the snippet you posted is potentially not helpful enough. Could you create a minimal sample (one that I can also run to reproduce the problem)?

Answer (score 2):

U are using `asyncMap` correctly.
Your issue might be that you add events to stream before `Streambuilder` starts to listen to `widget.model.results(widget.type)` stream.

Either use:
[BehaviorSubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html)

```
  final List<BehaviorSubject> _streamControllers = [
    BehaviorSubject<List<int>>(),
    BehaviorSubject<List<int>>(),
  ];
```

or add events AFTER widgets are built (or when we start to listen to them)

[How to use onListen callback to start producing events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205300/how-to-use-onlisten-callback-to-start-producing-events)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Stream every build therefore it will be always empty and won't update correctly. You have the same controller, but `asyncMap` is creating a new Stream under the hood. The docs:

> Creates a new stream with each data event of this stream asynchronously mapped to a new event.

The fix would be to save the instance of the stream after asyncMap is used. This can be done multiple ways. One would be to make a late initialized field inside your State.

```
late Stream<List<int>> myStream = widget.model.results(widget.type);
```

and then use this instance in the StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
  stream: myStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error');

    final List<int> results = snapshot.data;
    return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: results.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return _buildListTile(results[index]);
                  });
  })
```

But you can also save the instance in initState or completely outside the widget and make `Stream<List<int>> results(int index)` return the saved instance or make it the list like this:

```
List<Stream<List<int>>> results = _streamControllers
    .map((s) => s.stream.asyncMap((filter) async {
          final List<int> assets = await search(); //  Future
          return _results..addAll(assets);
        }))
    .toList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated my code and changed `results(int index)` to `results[]` with a `late` assignment as you suggested. Execution still halts at the `await search()` call and never resumes.. Any more ideas?

Comment: @FloatingRock Seems like we don't have enough information. I am not sure how you changed the code, but if you want I posted the code I was playing with here: https://gist.github.com/pr0gramista/ee95200dfec29febf00d4c7e9bd4b6e1 Maybe that will help you.